# Jquery and mootools with scroll method in socialengine

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mootools, socialengine

According to my requirement..If i scroll down with `200px`. I should show a div in the top of the page which stick there. I worked with an jquery which is working fine in my personal PC. Where I placed the same thing in my working PC its not working fine and showing an

```
error (Uncaught TypeError: Object function (el, nc){
    return document.id(el, nc, this.document);
} has no method 'noConflict')
```

my jquery is:

```
$.noConflict()
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

jQuery('#menu1').toggle(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 350);
});
```

In my project I have Mootools.I think the conflict was coming with that...can anybody please make sure of my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you get I see that the `$` is being used by Mootools.

Use `jQuery` instead of `$` and you should be fine. So try this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    jQuery('#menu1').toggle(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 350);
});
```

You could also do it with MooTools:

```
window.addEvent('scroll', function () {
    var scroll = window.getScroll().y;
    scroll > 350 ? $('menu1').show() : $('menu1').hide();
});
```

Anyway, keep in mind MooTools uses the dollar sign to get a element by ID (`$('myID')`), you can also use this instead: `document.id('myID')`, they are the same.

Comment: Thanq for the session